# IIf Function Based on User Defined Parameters

Tags: forms, ms-access, iif-function

I'm trying to develop a query based on parameters entered into a form.  I want to make sure that the query will still work even if the user chooses not to enter parameters (ex. start and end date) or if the user only enters half of the parameters (ex. user only enters start but not end date or end but not start date). This is what I want:

If start date and end date is null, then return all dates,

else, If start date is null, then return dates less than or equal to the given end date,

else, If end date is null, then return dates greater than or equal to the given start date,

else, Return all dates between the given start and end date

What I've come up with doesn't seem to evaluated beyond the first true statement and I'm not sure why.

```
IIf(IsNull([forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Start_Date]
And [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_End_Date]),  
[Volunteer_Date],  

IIf(IsNull([forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Start_Date]),  
<= [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_End_Date],  

IIf(IsNull([forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_End_Date]),  
>= [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Start_Date],  

(Between [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Start_Date] 
And [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_End_Date]))))
```

Comment: i think it would be easier checking dates with vba macro

Comment: "VBA macro" is contradictory in Access, where you have Macros (which don't use VBA) and VBA (which is not a macro). In Word/Excel, terminology is different. I think what is meant is coding it in VBA. Macros are just not a good solution at all in Access (until A2010, where they get error handling).

Comment: What is the query used for? If it's the Recordsource of a form or report, then don't include any criteria, and just open the form/report with the criteria as the WHERE parameter of the DoCmd.OpenForm/OpenReport command.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
WHERE (IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]!      [Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Name_Selection]),(People.PID) like "*",(People.PID)=[Forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Name_Selection]))

AND (IIf(IsNull([forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Start_Date]) AND IsNull([forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_End_Date]),(Volunteer.Volunteer_Date) like "*",([Volunteer].[Volunteer_Date]) Between [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_Start_Date] And [forms]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person]![Volunteer_Hours_By_Person_End_Date]))
```